# How to search into log files for a particular string?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm working on batch script to read a log file from a location (user specific )

The input search string is typed by user;

If string found, copy the whole line in another text file.

Expected:

- Enter location of log file: The path to Logfile\abclog.txt
- Enter search string : ERROR or error ( /i for insensitive )
- Lines containing ERROR or error are copied to new text file.

i have this so far as code :

```
@echo off 
set /p Input=Enter some text:
echo %Input% findstr "%Input%" < C:/logfile.txt
 if %errorlevel%==0 ( echo Found! logged files into newlog.txt
 ) else (
 echo No matches found )
```

Comment: If you have problems with at script or specific questions we are happy to help. Please understand that this is not a code factory wher you order and the community serves.

Comment: got it.. but very new to batch scripting. Hence the query..

Comment: So your LogFile contains Errors Lines that you hope to catch them ?  isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is something you could perform on Unix systems:

```
tail -F abclog.txt | grep --line-buffered -i ERROR > outputfile.txt
```

In a batch file in Windows you can do:

```
findstr /i "ERROR" logfile.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: thanks for the inputs! I am looking into somethin like @echo off
set /p Input=Enter some text:
echo %Input%
findstr "%Input%" < C:/logfile.text
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo Found! logged files into newlog.txt)
else ( 
echo No matches found
)
pause

Comment: @vortexbx - while this would work on *nix hosts, the batch-file tag is for Windows, so unfortunately this won't be of much help.

Comment: @SomethingDark  you are right, I read bash  not batch so my answer is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
@echo off 
cls & color 0B
echo(
Set /p "Location=Enter the file location to perform search> "
cls & echo(
echo You chose this location "%Location%"
echo(
set /p "Input=Enter text to search: "
set ResultFile=ResultFile.txt
findstr /r /i "%Input%" "%Location%" > %ResultFile%
 if %errorlevel%==0 (cls & Color 0A & echo Found the string "%Input%" into "%Location%" !
    ) else (cls & Color 0C & echo No matches found "%Input%" into "%Location%" !)
Echo Hit any key to open the file "%ResultFile%" !  
pause>nul 
start %ResultFile%
```